# Linux Failing Drives Cant Find the Drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, gentoo

I am being told I have a failing hard drive but no one can tell me which one. I have 2-146GB drives and 4-1TB drives. Accoring to my list I only see 2 of the actual drives? How can I get a list of the actual drives? How can I figure out which is bad? If I check in the HP ILO Storage it shows all disks are ok?

```
# lsblk -d
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0  60.6M  1 loop /usr/portage
sda     8:0    0 136.7G  0 disk
sdb     8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
zd0   230:0    0     2G  0 disk [SP]
zd16  230:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
zd32  230:32   0     3G  1 disk
```

Linux is Gentoo

Comment: I posit you are running zfs and the zd* block devices are zvols.  What does "sudo zpool status" say?

Comment: I normally use `lsscsi` to list things. It looks like `lsblk` has a `-a` option which shows empty drives. Depending on how it is failing, maybe that would show some other drives? Once you identify the failing drive, you can use `hdparm -i /dev/sda` to get it to print out the serial, etc., which hopefully corresponds to stuff printed on a physical label on the drive.

Comment: Try `cat /var/log/syslog | grep kernel | grep '/dev/sd\|/dev/zd'` to filter for any error messages being reported by disks. You say you are being told you have failing disks; by who or what? If it is unable to tell you which disk and why, it isn't exactly a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

The result here is rather technical, so beware...

Copy this text into a file, say $HOME/smartstat

```
#!/bin/bash
b="----------------" # 16 dashes
lsblk -p \
| grep disk \
| cut -d' ' -f1 \
| while read disk ;do 
    echo -e "\n$(tput rev)$b\n ${b: -2} $disk ${b: -2} \n$b$(tput sgr0)"
    sudo smartctl -a $disk
  done
```

Then do: `chmod 755 smartstat` (in Terminal, at the bash prompt) to set it as being an executable. After that `./smartstat` will run it... providing a wealth of information for each "disk" that lsblk recognizes *(append  `| less`  to use the text reader, instead of relying on terminal scrollback)*.

A disk/drive that has "SMART" tech embedded **MIGHT** show something that tells IF or even WHAT problems there exists in that drive - but there is a lot to read and ponder on.
You might need to read up on how to interpret all those numbers.

I have yet to see the output from a failed drive, so cannot advice about that.
Maybe others can fill in regarding it.

These may be helpful:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6983?page=0%2C1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes
https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ
https://serverfault.com/questions/419007/understanding-smartctl-a-output

*info:

smartctl is part of smartmontools, for ubuntu, can't tell for other distro's*

Comment: removed the comment.